# WebClient sometimes returns a HTTP 500 error

Tags: c#, iis, webclient

I'm facing a (for me) strange problem. From time to time a call to an IIS hosted textfile
fails with a 500 error. Retrying then succeeds.

The error message from the WebException is

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Server Error</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content-container">
      <fieldset>
        <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
        <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The used code is

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(cfg.User, cfg.Password);
    mydata = client.DownloadString(serverDir + "info.txt");
}
```

It is an https connection, the version of IIS is unknown. I don't have access to the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be easier if you could check Event Viewer for issues with IIS. If don't have access to the server where IIS is running, you can't exactly debug a 500 error. Talk with the people who have access to that server.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 500 error.